# Why my repository name and tags are not coming after building docker image using the docker file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am unable to see the name of my docker image (myimage1). It is as followes:-

[image: here]

The docker file I have used is :-

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER Dev
LABEL remarks = "Test Image"
RUN yum install update && yum install httpd -y && yum install update
```

I am using the command to build an image:-

```
docker build -t "myimage1" .
```

I am expecting image should be myimage1, not `<none>`

Comment: Spaces aren't allowed in tags, so do you really need the quotes?

Comment: Yes it an optional.

Comment: What are you expecting `yum install update` to do? That's not how you update packages and you don't need to run it again after installing things. Also, httpd docker images already exist